# internal and external js files stop working after ajax call - codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So I've been to this for days already. So what happens is that every time I am loading a new content/view inside the div with id inside. The content doesn't get the JS from the footer.php which is already loaded on my core controller. Here is the sample codes.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
$(document).on("click", "a[rel=tab]", function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: pageurl + '?rel=tab',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#inside').html(data);
        }
    });

    //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
    if (pageurl != window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({ path: pageurl }, '', pageurl);
    }
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.pathname + '?rel=tab',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#inside').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Inside here I already loaded my controller and all other configurations. So all I need to do is load the content between them which is already working. The only problem is that everytime it's working it wont load any javascript on the new content
**core/controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->load->model('playlist_model');
$this->load->helper('url_helper');
$this->load->model('song_info_model');
$this->load->library('zip');
}

public function load_page($page,$data = null, $return = FALSE){

        $this->load->view($page, $data);
    } 


public function template($page,$data = null){

    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
    $data['title'] = 'Users List';
    $playlist_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['folders'] = $this->playlist_model->get_folders();
    $data['playlists'] = $this->playlist_model->get_playlists();
    $data['user_folder'] = $this->playlist_model->get_playlist_by_user_id($id);
    $data['user_playlist'] = $this->playlist_model->get_playlist_by_folder();
    $data['playlist_title'] = $this->playlist_model->get_specific_playlist($playlist_id);
    $data['song_list'] = $this->playlist_model->get_songs_in_playlist($playlist_id);
    $data['session'] = $this->user_model->get_specific_user($id);
    if($this->session->has_userdata('user_email'))
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/player', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/modals', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/content', $data);
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else{
      redirect('users/login');        
    }
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}
public function index()
{
$data = array();
$data['main_song_lists'] = $this->song_info_model->get_song_list();

$this->load_page('dashboard',$data);

}
}
```

Comment: The response that you are loading / appending does not contain the header and footer section from the resulting page that is called in ajax?

Comment: because the header and footer is already loaded on first load. since I want the header and footer to be static. that means only a part of the div will change.

Comment: yeah i know i was just confirming that it wasnt loading scripts from that page again

Comment: oh. sorry. yeah. it's not loading the scripts once I change the content :(

Comment: What you are really saying is, any new JS aware bits loaded via your AJAX Call are not being recognised. i.e they are not triggering the expected events. So this is what is called "late binding" and something like .on() may help. Research it. I've done this on projects in the past but remember didley squat at the moment on it.

Comment: No, maybe try to check the js code? i am using .on() function. all the js that is pre loaded is not working on the next content. that's what i meant. the js is already loaded on the first load